# How to retrieve a specific data as a string from an array of list by passing a parameter?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array of list

```
"items": [{
        "id": 0,
        "message_No": "55",
        "message_Type": "I",
        "language_Code": null,
        "message": "Code Required",
        "errMsg": null
    },
    {
        "id": 0,
        "message_No": "48",
        "message_Type": "I",
        "language_Code": null,
        "message": "Code should not be greater than {0} characters",
        "errMsg": null
    }
]
```

My requirement is when i pass the message no as a parameter it should return the corresponding message as a string.

i.e, If i pass 55 as my parameter it should return "Code Required".
How can i implement that?

Comment: You data is in JSON type or string?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using `find`

```js
const data={
 "items": [{
   "id": 0,
   "message_No": "55",
   "message_Type": "I",
   "language_Code": null,
   "message": "Code Required",
   "errMsg": null
  },
  {
   "id": 0,
   "message_No": "48",
   "message_Type": "I",
   "language_Code": null,
   "message": "Code should not be greater than {0} characters",
   "errMsg": null
  }
 ]
}
let filtered=data.items.find(i=>i.message_No==='55');
console.log(filtered ? filtered.message : 'Not Found');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use find method in javascript.

```js
const items = [{
        "id": 0,
        "message_No": "55",
        "message_Type": "I",
        "language_Code": null,
        "message": "Code Required",
        "errMsg": null
    },
    {
        "id": 0,
        "message_No": "48",
        "message_Type": "I",
        "language_Code": null,
        "message": "Code should not be greater than {0} characters",
        "errMsg": null
    }
];

function getMessage(message_No){
  return items.find(o => o.message_No === message_No).message;
}

const message = getMessage('55');

console.log(message)
```